# Do counters go away when the creature that gave them dies

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When a creature card gives another creature counters does the counters go away when the creature that gave them dies.(the card does NOT say It gives is  a +1 +1 counter as long as it is on the field)

Comment: I noticed that you commented with a "Thank you [...]" on one of the answers. If you are satisfied with that answer, accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 6):

No, the counters stay where they are. Counters are a separate entity once they are placed on a permanent. If a creature says "other creatures get +1+1" and then leaves the battlefield, the bonus is lost. And if a creature with +1+1 counters on it leaves the battlefield, the counters go away. But in the scenario you described, the counters stay.

Comment: To be extra clear, permanents that say something like "Creatures you control get +1/+1" don't use counters at all. They just have that effect as long as they're on the battlefield. Similarly cards/effects that say "... get +1/+1 until end of turn" don't use counters. Only cards that actually say "+1/+1 counter" do.

Comment: @Jefromi I suppose technically one should mention that there are other kinds of counters, like -1/-1 counters and charge counters. But of course the point you make, that an effect does not use counters unless it includes the word "counter", is a good one.

Comment: @DavidZ Of course, if an effect does use the word "counter", that's no guarantee that it uses counters. :-)